# How do I use Gradle to implement an artifact in the custom jar task?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

Like this:

```kotlin
runtimeOnly(project.project(":project1").tasks.getByName<Jar>("shadowJar").archiveFile)
```

I do not want to use `runtimeOnly(project("project1"))`, because the module has more than 2 jar artifacts.

But this is not true.
result:

> org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of
> task ':project1:shadowJar' property 'archiveFile' before task
> ':project1:shadowJar' has completed is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `configuration` to use:

```
runtimeOnly project(path: ":project1", configuration: "shadow")
```

Comment: Thanks, I searched the `configuration` tutorial and tried to create the `shadow`, but it was already there. So I should just use this code instead of trying to create one. All my work was for nothing. Finally, I used `runtimeOnly(project(":project1", "shadow"))`.